# The system is running in low-graphics mode when Installing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, intel-hd

My laptop is Fujitsu AH532 Lifebook.
I'm trying to clean install Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on my laptop with a failed Nvidia GPU, however I want to run it with Intel HD graphics, how do I reconfigure it?
Whenever I try to install it, it says "xorg failed to idle channel 2" after that  "The system is running in low-graphics mode, after that everything goes blank. 
I tried everything that's already on the net. None of these work.

System Specs: i3-3110m
              Intel HD 4000
              Nvidia GT 620m (failed)
              8GB Ram

Comment: Have you tried adding `nomodeset` to the kernel parameters prior to installation?

Answer (score 0):

At the grub boot selection screen tap <kbd>e</kbd> and place the kernel parameter `nomodeset` on the line that begins with `linux` the order of these parameters doesn't really matter, but to avoid confusion I would place it between the `quiet` and `splash` parameters preserving the spaces between the parameters.

Having edited the boot command line you can now hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the modified parameters, then follow the [directions to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), and remove the installation media when prompted. You should now be able to boot into your newly installed system normally.

If anything about this answer is unclear, drop me a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: What do I do after that? Everytime i restart the laptop it goes ahead and does the same thing.

Comment: @A.Rahman Updated answer